# UITableViewCell background image disappears after scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am initializing a `EventEditViewController` to add a new event with the following code:

```
- (void)presentEventEditViewControllerWithEventStore:(EKEventStore*)eventStore
{
    EKEventEditViewController* vc = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
    vc.eventStore = eventStore;
    vc.delegate = self; // Probably self


    EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = @"";
    event.startDate = [NSDate date];
    event.endDate = [NSDate date];
    event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@""];
    event.notes = @"";
    event.allDay = NO;
    vc.event = event;

    vc.editViewDelegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    UITableView *tableView = ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView;

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
        //((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        for (NSInteger j = 0; j < [tableView numberOfSections]; ++j)
        {
            for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:j]; ++i)
            {
                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath     indexPathForRow:i inSection:j]];

                    cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background-1.png"]];
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                }
            }
    }
 }
```

The UITableView appears as it should, but when I start scrolling until a `UITableViewCell` is not on the iPhone's screen anymore and then scroll back, the `TableViewCell` forgets its image and turns into a standard `UITableViewCell` (without any background image or customization).

Screenshot before scrolling: http://postimg.org/image/vzlj3t5o9/)

Screenshot after scrolling: (http://postimg.org/image/c30836v2v/)

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to manage the appearance of table cells outside of the context of a a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation, for a few reasons. But since you won't be able to subclass the various view controllers involved in the `EKEventEditViewController`'s workflow, you won't be able to write an implementation of these methods in the usual way. However, you can use some of Objective-C's reflection and runtime to interject your own `UITableViewDataSource` implementations.

The basic idea is to switch out the table view's data source with one you control, but still rely on the implementations provided by the Event Kit UI framework, and only apply visual tweaks to the cells they return. Follows is my interface and implementation of `FakeTableViewDataSource`:

```
@interface FakeTableViewDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic) id<UITableViewDataSource> realDataSource;

@end

@implementation FakeTableViewDataSource


- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    BOOL responds = [super respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    if (!responds && self.realDataSource) {
        responds = [self.realDataSource respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    }

    return responds;
}


- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    if ([self.realDataSource respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.realDataSource];
    }
    else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.realDataSource tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

You'd implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to implement your app's particular visual tweaks, I chose the text label color as it was obvious if it had worked or not.

Now, in your `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method, instead of iterating the cells, swap out the data sources. My implementation is as shown:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UITableViewController class]]) {
        UITableView *tableView = ((UITableViewController *)viewController).tableView;
        if (![tableView.dataSource isKindOfClass:[FakeTableViewDataSource class]]) {
            FakeTableViewDataSource *fakeDataSource = [[FakeTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
            fakeDataSource.realDataSource = tableView.dataSource;
            tableView.dataSource = fakeDataSource;
            [self.fakeDataSources addObject:fakeDataSource];
        }
    }
}
```

It should be said that tampering with the frameworks in such a way is potentially risky from a maintainability point of view and an app store approval point of view. So do take care when using techniques like this.

Comment: @apptunes you're welcome, this worked with the background image and everything as well?